# Keras: Transfer Learning - Image scaling worsens performance of the model significantly

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I am working on an image classification problem with keras and tensorflow. I am using the VGG16 model with Imagenet weights and I am importing my data using the ImageDataGenerator from Keras.

Now I've been reading that one should **always rescale the images** using 1./255 for an efficient tranining. However, once I implement the scaling my model performs significantly worse than before. Changing the learning rate and batch size didn't help either.

Now I am questioning whether this is possible or if my model has some error. I am using standard .jpg image files.

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
IMAGE_SIZE = 224
BATCH_SIZE = 32

num_classes = 27

main_path = "C:/Users/abc/data"

final_path = os.path.join(main_path, "ML_DATA")
labels = listdir(gesamt_path)


data_generator = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255, ### rescaling done here
                                    validation_split=0.20)

train_generator = data_generator.flow_from_directory(final_path, target_size=(IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE), shuffle=True, seed=13,
                                                     class_mode='categorical', batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, subset="training")

validation_generator = data_generator.flow_from_directory(final_path, target_size=(IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE), shuffle=False, seed=13,
                                                     class_mode='categorical', batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, subset="validation")
```

Model definition and training

```
vgg16_model = keras.applications.vgg16.VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=True)
model = Sequential()
for layer in vgg16_model.layers[:-1]:
    model.add(layer)


for layer in model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False

model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(Adam(lr=.001), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit_generator(train_generator,
                    validation_data=validation_generator, 
                    epochs=85, verbose=1,callbacks=[tbCallBack,earlystopCallback])
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be that Imagenet Weights are not compatible with your new image dimension.

I see that your only trainable layer is the very last layer, a dense layer, which doesn’t know anything about image dimension. My suggestion is to also let the first few convolutional layers to be trainable, so that those layers can adapt to the rescaling.

Comment: I have the same issue. I am using ```ResNet50```. I will try to train the CNN layers as well.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that ResNet subtracts the per-pixel mean from its image data, instead of dividing by 255. Source: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.03385.pdf under `3.4 Implementation`

Answer (score -1):

Working with ResNet and imagenet weights I improved my results using:

`ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=preprocess_input)`

With rescaling I obtained worse results too.

This information was useful to me:

https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN/issues/231